# Magento 2: Echo store VAT number

Tags: magento2, cms, vat, stores

In Magento 1, to echo the store VAT number from a CMS page, I'd use `{{config path="general/store_information/merchant_vat_number"}}`. How do I do this in Magento 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom widget to do this.
Create a new module, `Name_ConfigValueWidget`.

In `etc/widget.xml`, use the following:

```
<widgets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Widget:etc/widget.xsd">
    <widget id="config_value" class="Name\ConfigValueWidget\Block\Widget\ConfigValue"
            placeholder_image="Magento_Cms::images/widget_block.png">
        <label translate="true">Config Value</label>
        <description translate="true">Product Showcase</description>
        <parameters>

            <parameter name="path" xsi:type="text" required="true" visible="true">
                <label translate="true">Path</label>
            </parameter>

        </parameters>
    </widget>
</widgets>
```

Now create the block class in `Block/Widget/ConfigValue.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Name\ConfigValueWidget\Block\Widget;


use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface;

class ConfigValue extends Template implements BlockInterface
{
    protected $_scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        array $data
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);

        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->setTemplate('Name_ConfigValueWidget::configvalue.phtml');
    }

    public function getValue()
    {
        $path = $this->getData('path');

        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            $path,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }
}
```

Now create the template file `view/frontend/templates/configvalue.phtml`:

```
<span>
    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getValue() ?>
</span>
```

After running `setup:upgrade` and clearing the cache, you can use this widget in a CMS page like this:
`{{widget type="Name\ConfigValueWidget\Block\Widget\ConfigValue" path="general/store_information/merchant_vat_number"}}`

Comment: Hi Aaron, thank you for responding. I noticed you left some of your code in the above example - `AAllen_Sandbox::configvalue.phtml`. What should I put here, instead of AAllen_Sandbox? Thanks

Comment: Yeah, it should be whatever you defined the module as, for example `Name_ConfigValueWidget::configvalue.phtml`.